# Dates with MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to store datetime in to mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778428/best-way-to-store-datetime-in-to-mongodb)

I am curious to know what others are using for storing dates in MongoDB. I need to store dates like user_created, user_lastLogin, ...etc.  Has anyone had any experiences in why one approach may be better than another?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778428/best-way-to-store-datetime-in-to-mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

the driver for your language should allow you to use that language's date type/object.