# `mongo` Query To Purge Old Entries

Tags: mongodb

Anyone have a handy `mongo` command to remove all entries from a DB that are older than X date/ X days?

Basically have a dev and production DB, I'm looking to prune the dev DB out a bit to limit size.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: They **mostly** have datetime fields.  Let's assume they all do for brevity's sake.  I can always sort it by _id and only keep the last X documents if I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this from the mongo shell.

```
var older=Date.parse("2013-03-01"),collection=db.so,all=collection.find();
all.forEach(function(doc) { var ts = doc._id.getTimestamp();
    if (ts < older) { collection.remove(doc); } });
```

The above line (which you'd paste into the shell) will delete all documents in the specified collection (`collection=db.so`) created before the first of March, 2013. It relies on the fact that each `ObjectId` has an embedded `timestamp` (based on the `timestamp` of document creation ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#objectid))), which can be retrieved and used.

You could of course change the query to look for a specific timestamp field in a document.

```
if (doc.timestampField < older) { collection.remove(doc); } })
```

Comment: It did crash my MongoDB instance when I ran this, however I'm 95% sure this will work as advertised.  I'll run this tonight when traffic is low and see how she goes.  Thanks!

Comment: You might want to move the logic to a small app written in your favorite programming language. There seems to be a limit to the number of lines/complexity of the mongodb shell JS support, so I couldn't do much with it, nor add any robustness. I couldn't get it to crash, but my developer workstation didn't have much data that I could delete.

Comment: Yeah, better idea for sure.  I should be able to whip something up pretty easily, the only thing I wonder about is the _id.getTimestamp().  Looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452021/getting-timestamp-from-mongodb-id  I don't think it will be a problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mongo concept of deleting data after some specified amount of time, Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL.

Please refer below link to do so
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.