# Mongo db . Read records while maintaining last readrecord information

Tags: sql, mongodb

My problem is as follows : On a daily basis , records are appended into the Mongo database . There is no specific column for showing timestamp or id (The user has designed the table thus). Whilst retrieving records from the database , is there any meta information (such as the BSON document_id) which will help to retrieve records based on a certain time range (11-12-2013 to 12-12-2013 ). ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timestamp can be extracted from ObjectId [Mongo dcs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)
More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452021/getting-timestamp-from-mongodb-id)

Comment: But is there any created timestamp or any other timestamp as part of the metadata generated by database while storing the BSON Documents?