# Convert Mongodb ObjectId to timestamp within AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, templates

```
<li ng-repeat="poll in polls">
    <span>{{poll._id.getTimestamp() | date:'shortTime'}}</span>
</li>
```

Each poll object has an ObjectId like this one: `"5629a520f7ca231816cd373e"` How do I convert this to a timestamp within an AngularJS template? The above code is not producing any output.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452021/getting-timestamp-from-mongodb-id

Comment: @KennethJohn Yeah I tried this approach, as you can probably tell from my code snippet in the question. This doesn't seem to work though. I'm not quite sure why...

Comment: If your poll._id = "5629a520f7ca231816cd373e", then what is the getTimestamp() method. Have you manually defined this method?

Comment: @KennethJohn No I haven't defined the method. I tried `poll._id..substring(0,8)` but I don't think that's how MongoDB saves the date inside the id because this produced weird results as well (letters in the first 8 characters for some strings)

Comment: `var timestamp ="5629a520f7ca231816cd373e".toString().substring(0,8);`
undefined
var date = new Date( parseInt( timestamp, 16 ) * 1000 );
undefined
date
Thu Oct 22 2015 23:10:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: I just happened to convert it into  a timestamp and it did appear to be a proper one - **Thu Oct 22 2015 23:10:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)**

Comment: @KennethJohn What about this one then: `5629a520f7ca231816cd373e`

Comment: Well, that's the one which I converted. Can you check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kensplanet/z8t2tk0z/