# Mongoose use only createdAt timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following message schema in mongoose:

```
var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userID: { type: ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
  text:   { type: String, required: true }
},
{
  timestamps: true
});
```

Is there anyway to ignore the updatedAt timestamp? Messages won't be updated so updatedAt will be wasted space

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Edit** I've amended the answer to reflect the better option to use the default as per @JohnnyHK

You can handle this yourself by declaring the `createdAt` (or whatever you want to call it) in your schema:

```
mongoose.Schema({
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  ...
```

Alternatively we can also update values on new document in a pre save hook:

```
messageSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (!this.created) this.created = new Date;
  next();
})
```

Along those lines is also the flag [isNew](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isNew) which you can use to check if a document is new.

```
messageSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.isNew) this.created = new Date;
  next();
})
```

Comment: You can skip the middleware if you define a default: `created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }`

Comment: Yes of course. My bad. I've had weird unwanted effects from defaults that I explicitly write it all out now but in this case it's much better.

Answer (score 75):

Maybe even better with Mongoose v5 is to do the following;

```
const schema = new Schema({
  // Your schema...
}, {
  timestamps: { createdAt: true, updatedAt: false }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Older topic but there may be a better option depending on your schema...
If you're sticking with the default of having mongodb/mongoose auto-gen _id, there's already a timestamp built in.  If all you need is "created" and not "updated" just use...

document._id.getTimestamp();

From MongoDB docs here...
[ObjectId.getTimestamp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp)

And Here... [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452021/getting-timestamp-from-mongodb-id)

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose timestamp interface has these optional fields.

```
interface SchemaTimestampsConfig {
    createdAt?: boolean | string;
    updatedAt?: boolean | string;
    currentTime?: () => (Date | number);
  }
```

We can pass the boolean for the field we want(`createdAt: true` and `updatedAt: true` will add both fields).
We can use the currentTime function to overwrite the date format.

example:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { Schema } = mongoose;
const annotationType = ['NOTES', 'COMMENTS'];
const referenceType = ['TASKS', 'NOTES'];
const AnnotationSchema = new Schema(
  {
    sellerOrgId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    createdById: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    annotationType: {
      type: String,
      enum: annotationType,
    },
    reference: {
      id: { type: String, index: true },
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: referenceType,
      },
    },
    data: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  },
  { timestamps: { createdAt: true },
);
const AnnotationModel = mongoose.models.annotation || mongoose.model('annotation', AnnotationSchema);
export { AnnotationModel, AnnotationSchema };
```