# Add timestamp from each Objectid to all mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a huge dataset of documents, but when I got the data, I forgot append a timestamp of the time were created each of them.

How I can use the ObjectID timestamp of each document to append the timestamp when were created for all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the initial wrong answer.

---

That being said, the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html) says for *python* that, you can get the timestamp in EPOCH time in the first 4 bytes of your objectID.

I read somewhere else ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452021/getting-timestamp-from-mongodb-id)), that in Javascript, you have a method `.getTimestamp()`. You should tell us the language you need in order to get your function, but I guess you got the logic anyway. :)

Comment: Yes that was the way, with the python mongoDB library you can extract the date and then append it in the document.

Comment: @Maxtrix That was an unexpected comment 1 year and a half later haha

Comment: I forgot totally about my account and I just realized that your answer was the thing that I used at that time.