# Query mongoDB by date document created using pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Lots of solutions to querying mongoDB using date/time field in MongoDB but what if the mongo doc doesn't have a date/time field?

I've noticed that when I hover the mouse over a document _id (using NoSQLBooster for MongoDB) I get a "createdAt" dropdown (see screenshot below). Just wondering if there is anyway to do a query using pymongo where documents are filtered based on a date/time range using their "createdAt" metadata?

[image: screen shot of createdAt metadata]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB the id of the docs contains the timestamp of creation, this is mentioned on [this other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452021/getting-timestamp-from-mongodb-id/27888841)
You can make a script that insert a date/field using this information to perform those queries or perform the query directly to using the objectId [as in here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date)

Comment: Legend! thanks! the answer contained in your last link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date) was what I was after. It's written in Java but I should be able to adjust it to python with no worries. I'll let you know how I go! thanks again!