# Sorting timestamp in descending order in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
Product.find({
            userId: data.id
        },null,{ $sort :{ createdOn : -1}},function(err, products) {...});
```

I want to sort createdOn in desc order and am not getting the desire result

note: createdOn is a timestamp and Iam using mongodb 1.3.19

please help!!

Comment: This does not look like a correct syntax. Does it produce any result?

Comment: yes all the products are displayed but not sorted i just want to sort these products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Product.find({
        userId: data.id
    },null,{ sort :{ createdOn : -1}},function(err, products) {...});
```

I only have to remove $ from $sort it works fine for me now :)

Answer (score 3):

You are quite close. I assume you're using Mongoose (it looks like it).

The correct syntax should be:

```
Product.find({userId: data.id}, null)
    .sort('-createdOn')
    .exec(function(err, products) { ... });
```

Take a look at the [documentation for the Query object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) for more info.

Comment: thanx for the response but i figured it out by my self :)

Comment: Awesome! It's always better that way, since it means you'll remember it better.