# Rails datetime_select Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, datetime

Rails ~ 4.2.1

Mongoid ~ 4.0.2

in _form.html.erb, the code looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @workout %>
  <%= f.label :date%>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

in Workout.rb, the code looks like this:

```
class Workout
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :date, type: DateTime
end
```

I naively thought `The View` could send `{"workou[date]" => "2015/06/20 10:10"}` to the `Controller`, but actually, it sent `{"workout[date(1i)]" => "2015", workout[date(2i)] => "06", ... workout[date(5i)] => "10"}`. In the end, in Mongo workout collection, it stored the time separately.

I want Mongo DB to store them in one field, type as `DateTime`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You ask for Datetime, but maybe my answer (using Date type) can lead you the way too. Let's see.*

This answer suggests the [Best way to store date/time in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3778820/1566187). That is if you can you should choose native JavaScript Date objects.

The way I solve my issue (with Date object) was as follows.

I use the `Date` field type in my models. E.g. the [Event](https://github.com/Elyasin/Come-Malaka-Expenses/blob/master/app/models/event.rb) model has two date types, `from_date` and `end_date`.

In the [controller (e.g. `new` method)](https://github.com/Elyasin/Come-Malaka-Expenses/blob/master/app/controllers/events_controller.rb) you can use the `Date` object as usual, no special treatment in my case. I guess for you it is the same. E.g. `Date.current` or `Date.current+3.days`.
Note the `create` method does not specifically manipulate `Date` objects. The parameters from the web view form are taken as is.

In the [view](https://github.com/Elyasin/Come-Malaka-Expenses/blob/master/app/views/events/new.html.haml) I use the `date_field` helper. It is an input field of type date. Note that currently Google Chrome supports the date field type, so you will see a date picker pop up. Other browsers don't support the field yet, so it is a simple input field for them. I use [jQuery Datepicker](https://github.com/Elyasin/Come-Malaka-Expenses/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js) in case the browser does not support the input date type field, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    if ( $('[type="date"]').prop('type') !== 'date' ) {
        $('input[type="date"]').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
    }
    ...
});
```

> So in your case maybe you could do something analogue to that
>   solution. Probably there is no `datetime_field` helper method, but a
>   simple input field could do and you use JS to ensure you are saving a
>   native JS Date/Datetime object for the corresponding field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It help me a lot.  I think I will go with the Javascript solution!

Comment: Happy I could help. Please feel free to upvote if helpful.