# How to store a time value in MongoDB using SailsJS v0.11.3?

Tags: node.js, datetime, time, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm working with SailsJS and MongoDB and I have an API that has two models and I want to store `Date and Time separately` but as [in the official documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes) said it doesn't have a typeof `Time` attribute, just `Date` and `DateTime`. So, I'm using DateTime to store Time values.

I send the values in the request to be stored in the database, I have no problem to store `dates`, I just send a value like:

```
2015-12-16
```

and that's it, it is stored in the table with no problem, but when I want to store a `Time` value like:

```
19:23:12
```

it doesn't works. The error is:

```
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
  "model": "ReTime",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "value": [
      {
        "rule": "datetime",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a datetime (instead of \"19:23:12\", which is a string)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, any idea how to send the time value to be stored in a `DateTime` attribute?

I also have tried to send it in different formats like:

- `0000-00-00T19:23:12.000Z`
- `0000-00-00T19:23:12`
- `T19:23:12.000Z`
- `19:23:12.000Z`
- `19:23:12`

But any of them works fine.

Also I was thinking to store both values (Date and Time) in plain text, I mean typeof `String` attributes. But I need to make some queries and I don't know if it will affect the performance with the waterline ORM.

Please any kind of help will come in handy.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. The best would be to simply store the date and time as a `datetime` and parse them into separate values when you need to use them. [MongoDB will store this in BSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778428/best-way-to-store-date-time-in-mongodb?answertab=active#tab-top) and this will be the most efficient method.

Otherwise, you could use `string` and create a custom validation rule [as described in the Sails documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations#?custom-validation-rules).

Comment: Thank you so much! But how can I parse the data as you mention in order to use it and show to the user? I'm new in JavaScript

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how it will be returned from the database. Either it will come back as a JavaScript `Date` itself, or you will need to instantiate a new `Date` with the value you get. Check out the [Date reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) here. The top shows you how to instantiate (`var datetime = new Date(value_from_db);`). If you look at the prototype methods, you can see how to get various pieces of the date or time from the object.