# How to insert Javascript new Date() to MongoDB via Python?

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb

**Javascript**

```
theTime = new Date();
$.getJSON("/my_path",{
    the_time: theTime,
    format: 'json'
});
```

**Python**

```
var the_time = request.GET.the_time
# the entry
entry = {}
# other key/values are added to entry
entry['entry_time'] = entry_time
# the document
new_document = {}
# the entry is nested in the new document
new_document['k1']['n1'].append(entry)
collection.insert(new_document)
```

**MongoDB**

When I look at the entry in RockMongo, it is just showing:

```
"entry_time": "Mon Jan 18 2016 23:59:51 GMT+1000 (AEST)"
```

But according to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3778820/1063287

It should look something like this:

```
ISODate("2014-02-10T10:50:57.240Z")
```

How do I insert the Javascript new Date() to MongoDB as an `ISODate` via Python?

**Edit:**

I also just tried this:

**Javascript**

```
var theTime = new Date();
var theTime = theTime.toISOString()
$.getJSON("/my_path",{
    the_time: theTime,
    format: 'json'
});
```

And it results in this in RockMongo:

```
"entry_time": "2016-01-18T14:35:09.226Z"
```

Comment: Instead of passing a string to Mongo you should pass it a Python [`datetime` object](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/datetimes.html). [`dateutil.parser.parse`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) should be able to parse the string: `"Mon Jan 18 2016 23:59:51 GMT+1000 (AEST)"`

Comment: `from dateutil.parser import *` then `parse("Mon Jan 18 2016 23:59:51 GMT+1000 (AEST)")` returns `datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 18, 23, 59, 51, tzinfo=tzlocal())`.

Comment: and what is wrong with you getting `datetime` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
var date = new Date();
var isoDateString =  date.toISOString();
$.getJSON("/save_date",{isoDateString: isoDateString, format: 'json'}, function(results) {
});
```

Parse UTC date string in Python and save date object into MongoDB.

**Python**

```
import datetime
isoDateString = request.GET.isoDateString
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(isoDateString, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
document = {}
document['date_object'] = date_object
# define database
dbname = 'my_database'
# define collection
collection = db.my_collection
# insert document
collection.insert(document);
```

**Result**

```
"date_object" : ISODate("2016-08-21T06:41:19.319Z"),
```

Hope this help you.