# MongoDB Date.now() format different from new Date(string) format

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I'm struggling to understand the logic behind MongoDB date formatting, if I save a field like so:

```
date: Date.now()
```

in the database looks like:

```
date: 1633186879027
```

I have a date like `2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00` , and I save it like so:

```
date: "2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00"
```

in the database looks like:

```
date: "2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00"
```

and it's not what I want cause it's a string and I can't sort stuff by date then.

so i tried to save it like so:

```
date: new Date("2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00")
```

and in the database looks like:

```
date: 2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00
```

without brakets, as Mongodb does for strings, so must not be a string either

how am I supposed to save it so that it looks like the first one (`1633186879027`)?
because I then need to sort stuff by date and I think that's the correct format to use?

Comment: refer [mongodb date doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) and similar [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778428/best-way-to-store-date-time-in-mongodb).

Comment: Be aware, your client application/shell may format the date value based on some application settings and/or locale data. Which application/shell do you use?

Comment: I use Node, on vscode

Comment: @turivishal the documentation doesn't explain how to save it as a number sequence as Date.now() does by default, its examples are also horrible and incomplete to put it lightly

Comment: @turivishal and the example in the link ({date: ISODate()}) returns error ISODate is not defined in Node.js

Comment: @NathanBernard the documentation says "*`new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>")` returns the ISODate with the specified date.*" so the recommended approach is `new Date()` and ISODate method is for shell. second it is possible to do sort operation in ISO date.

Comment: why does it save Date.now() as a number by default then if the recommended format is js date object?

Comment: it will not save any default format, you have to set manually, [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) will return number of milliseconds and [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) will return an date object.

Comment: @NathanBernard there is no restriction, you can save in any format, the recommended way is `new Date()` means ISODate format, it will save as BSON `$date` type in mongodb. because it supports almost all operations that we do in numeric timestamp. and there are lots of [Date aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators).

Comment: ok thanks, I saved it as new Date() but now when I retrieve it and do .toString() it throws error cannot do .toString of undefined, which by documentation is supposed to turn it back to string

Comment: Your timestamp is in one of the formats supported by ECMA-262 for parsing by *Date.parse*, which returns a time value. So consider `date: Date.parse("2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00")`, which is equivalent to `date: new Date("2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00").getTime()` but less to type.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores data using BSON.  The definition is [here](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html)

A datetime is stored as the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 using a 64-bit integer.

`Date.now()` returns an integer, so the sample data would be stored as BSON type `\x12` with the value `1633186879027`.

`new Date("2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00")` would be stored as BSON type `\x09` with the value `1630090838000`.

The output `date: 2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00` was generated by the driver or application on the client side after it was retrieved.

MongoDB directly support sorting on dates.

Also note that if you have dates stored as strings like `"2021-08-27T19:00:38.000+00:00"`, a lexicographical sort of those string would put them in chronological order.

Comment: from what I know MongoDB doesn't support lexicographical sorting? I'm using aggregate to query the db

Comment: lexicographical sorting is how strings are sorted.

Comment: I honestly thought that in 2021 a popular db like MongoDB had such a functionality, but I don't think it actually does, the tests I did via pipeline aggregation didn't work that way. Not very familiar with lexicographical but it didn't sort correctly dates as strings